# Firebase analytics production events not containing all param data when comparing to dev environment

Tags: react-native, google-analytics, firebase-analytics, react-native-firebase

[image]

[image]

Looking at the events from last 30 mins if you count all the different events types you get a sum very far from the overall event count. (By example if you count the language type ones)

It appears like firebase is counting some events it has absolutely no data for...

The issue cannot be replicated in the dev environment.

Any clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research I found that **adding custom definitions (custom dimensions) in Firebase analytics for the params that were needed in the reports** was a requirement.

[image]

IMPORTANT: after adding custom dimensions for the params needed in the reports, you have to **wait for 24h - 48h** to see the big difference in firebase dashboard event data.

Sources:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aaQoqGELrQ4&t=774s

https://medium.com/lost-but-coding/setting-up-firebase-analytics-event-custom-parameters-dimensions-and-metrics-219cc3f3c356